# Downloading Data from Server in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I store data for my app as a JSON file on my server.  On starting the app, the data is downloaded as expected, however, when the data on the server is updated, it doesn't update in the app.  It takes probably a couple of hours before I can return to the app again, without making any changes, and this time the data will have been updated.  I was wondering if the data is maybe being catched, and if so, how to refresh it each time the component is displayed?

I think this is the relevant code (I've cut out bits I don't think are relevant)

```js
const LatestNews = ({ navigation }) => {

       const fileUrl = "http://www.myserver.co.uk/latestnews.json";
       const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    const getData = async () => {
      const resp = await fetch(fileUrl);
      const data2 = await resp.json();    
      setData(data2);
    };

    //on first mount, fetch data.
      useEffect(() => {
        getData();
      }, [data]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by data didn't update in the app, did you close the app and reopen but the data is still not updated?

Comment: It takes about an hour before the data displayed in the app matches the data on the server once it has been changed on the server.  Does this even if I restart the app.

Comment: Open network tab in devtools and see if it's fetching when you navigate to the screen

Comment: Thank You, that seems to have fixed it!  I actually added the headers as suggested in the other question, and removed the [data] from between the [ ], not sure exactly which one did the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't used data dependency in useeffect.
useEffect(() => {
getData();
}, []);`

Comment: I must admit, I don't really understand what should go in the [ ], but I've tried it with and without data in there and it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I did this and added a no-cache header as suggested in the comments to my original question.  Not sure which one did the trick, but I suspect both might have been needed?